# How to change color and thickness of headsepline and fromrule in scrlttr2?

Tags: color, scrlttr2

I want to change the color and thickness of headsepline and fromrule using the standard scrlttr2 class with the options:

```
headsepline=on
fromrule=aftername
```

Comment: You are using a very old version of KOMAscript (v3.12). The current version is 3.18. If you have to use 3.12, you have change to `scrpage2` and use other commands. Start by updating KOMAscript.

Comment: That said, I used `version=3.12`on my MWE, and it worked without problem. Are you sure you are not copying any invisible characters when you copy-paste into your Latex-editor?

Comment: Installed texlive from source. Now I dont get error messages anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following MWE gives red, 5pt line on page one and two:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,xcolor}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,       % Syntax error corrected 8.2.2020
            headsepline=5pt:,
            fromrule=aftername}

\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{fromrule}{\color{red}}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{fromrulethickness}{5pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
            Ernst Hemingway\\
            Main street\\
            2300\enspace\ PAMPLONA%
}

\setkomavar{yourref}{---}
\setkomavar{myref}{2013--999}
\setkomavar{date}{18. januar 2013}

\opening{}

Bulls are nice, but the last general meeting was about one year ago.
I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.

\pagebreak

I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.


\closing{Thank you}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

See page 226 and page 54 in the [KOMA-script manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (v3.18).

[image]
[image]

Comment: @stackunderflow - Does it work if you replace `\KOMAoption` with `\KOMAoptions`?